# How to set color to certain pixels of an image

Tags: android

I have an image in an ImageView. I would like to set certain pixels to red. I have made some progress, but the created image has lost its colour.

```
 iv.setImageBitmap(processingBitmap(bitmap));

  private Bitmap processingBitmap(Bitmap src){

        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());

        for(int x = 0; x < src.getWidth(); x++){
         for(int y = 0; y < src.getHeight(); y++){
          int pixelColor = src.getPixel(x, y);
          int newPixel= Color.rgb(pixelColor, pixelColor, pixelColor);
          dest.setPixel(x, y, newPixel);
         }
        }

        for (int i=5; i<50; i++)
        {
        dest.setPixel(i, i, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        }

        return dest;
       }
```

[image]

If I use  `Bitmap dest = src.copy(src.getConfig(), src.isMutable());` instead of  `Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());` I get an error to the  `iv.setImageBitmap(processingBitmap(bitmap));` line:

> 09-06 18:03:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(811): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException 09-06 18:03:37.226:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(811):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:847)

I also don't know why do I have to copy-paste all the pixels and after then set those pixels to red I want. If I use only

```
 for (int i=5; i<50; i++)
        {
        dest.setPixel(i, i, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        }
```

I get a black image with the red line.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Color.rgb() takes 3 bytes as Red, Green, Blue. You are tring to set the pixel-color on each of them.
Better try something like this

```
byte blue = (byte) ((pixelColor & 0xff));
byte green = (byte) (((pixelColor >> 8) & 0xff));
byte red = (byte) (((pixelColor >> 16) & 0xff));
int newPixel= Color.rgb(red , green , blue);
```